# Replacing equations with text + count

Tags: vba, ms-word, equation

I have a document with Word equation objects and I want to remove them from the document, place them in a new document, and leave a callout with a number in the original document, with a macro. The equations are in-line and on separate lines.

Ex:

Original
This is my equation *x=y<sup>2</sup> *.
Here is my second equation:
a + b +c

After:
This is my equation <Equation 001>.
Here is my second equation:
<Equation 002>

I have looked at OMaths.Count, Insert, CaptionLabel, Replace, CrossReference, and I can't get any of them to work--I don't know enough to even know what function I would need.

```
    Sub ReplaceEquationsReference()
    Dim Equation As OMath
    Dim i As Integer
    With ActiveDocument
        .DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
        For i = 1 To .OMaths.Count
            Set Equation = .OMaths.Item(i)
            Equation.Range.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
        Next
        .SelectAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
        .DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone

'Something in here to insert automated text'

        Selection.Cut
        Documents.Add.Content.Paste

    End With
    End Sub
```

I found a way to add equation captions, which gets me mostly there. But my problem is that I want to the captions to be copied with the equations to a new document.

```
    Sub ReplaceEquationsReference()
    Dim Equation As OMath
    Dim i As Integer
    With ActiveDocument
    For Each Equation In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        Equation.Range.InsertCaption Label:=wdCaptionEquation
    Next
        .DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
        For i = 1 To .OMaths.Count
            Set Equation = .OMaths.Item(i)
            Equation.Range.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
        Next
        .SelectAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
        .DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
        Selection.Cut
        Documents.Add.Content.Paste
    'To run InsertCaption Label in new document'

    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a basic facility (copy equations to a new document, label them in the new document and replace the originals with a plain text identifier + sequence number) you could use something like the following. If you need to enable editing via `Equation.Range.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone` then you should put the necessary code back in

```
Sub extractEqs()
Dim docSource As Word.Document
Dim docTarget As Word.Document
Dim eq As Word.OMath
Dim i As Long
Dim rngSource As Word.Range
Dim rngTarget As Word.Range
Dim txtCaption As String

i = 0
Set docSource = ActiveDocument
Set docTarget = Application.Documents.Add("Normal")

For Each eq In docSource.OMaths
  Set rngSource = eq.Range
  Set rngTarget = docTarget.Range(docTarget.Content.End - 1, docTarget.Content.End - 1)
  rngTarget.FormattedText = rngSource.FormattedText
  
  ' add a couple of paras and a caption after each EQ
  docTarget.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
  i = i + 1
  txtCaption = "<Equation " & Right("00" & CStr(i), 3) & ">"
  docTarget.Content.InsertAfter txtCaption
  docTarget.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
  
  ' replace the original equation by the plaintext caption
  rngSource.Delete
  rngSource.Text = txtCaption
Next

docTarget.SaveAs2 "g:\test\eqtarget.docx", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
docTarget.Close
Set rngSource = Nothing
Set rngTarget = Nothing
Set docTarget = Nothing
Set docSource = Nothing
End Sub
```

The `InsertCaption` method inserts a standard caption that contains a `{ SEQ Equation }` field. If you wanted to use a SEQuence field to provide the numbering, the above code can be changed fairly easily to do that.

Otherwise, if you want to copy the Equation *and* any caption (with caption text) that might exist, you should modify your question and describe where your captions can be found (e.g. are they in a new paragraph after the Equation, in the same paragraph after the Equation and a tab character, or what?)

Comment: This is AMAZING! Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed the macro to do.